# gwt - RequestFactory usage, missing content in returned EntityProxy

Tags: gwt

my environment:
- RequestFactory (GWT 2.5rc2, before 2.5rc1 and 2.4 - makes no difference regarding the question)
- Hibernate
- Spring's OpenSessionInView Filter (Session per Request)

I want to persist an EntityProxy with basically a Structure like follows:

```
EntityProxy_A
  ... other properties ...
  --> Set<EntityProxy_B setEntProxB;
    -->  EntityProxy_C entProxC;
    -->  EntityProxy_D entProxC;
```

My request methods are implemended in a class separate from my domain class (locator concept). Therefore I don't use  InstanceRequest persist().

**Solution/Question 1 - should the following approach work:**

I have request methods like

```
Request<EntityProxy_A> save(EntityProxy_A);  
Request<EntityProxy_A> createNew();
```

I use createNew() to get an instance of EntityProxy_A (initialized with values regarding "... other properties ..." and already persisted in the db) to the client. Important to mention no Set of EntityProxy_B is created at that point.

In the OnSuccess of createNew() I do

```
 public void onSuccess(EntityProxy_A response) {
   MyRequest request = myRequestFactory.getMyRequest();
   EntityProxy_A editableA = request.edit(response);
   ...
```

I then with "request" create my EntityProxy_B,C,D and assemble everything (like listed above).

Now i call

```
request.save(editableA)
       .with("setEntProxB",
             "setEntProxB.entProxC",
             "setEntProxB.entProxD")
       .fire(Receiver<EntityProxy_A>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(EntityProxy_A response) {
             .......
          }
```

The parameter Entity_A arrives at my request method impl at the server with all its childs, is then persisted, everything shows up in the db fine.

If I call on the hibernate session a forced flush (remember I use OpenSessionInView, so normally everything is persisted after I leave the request method impl) I can even see all the ID's for the newly created/persisted instances of EntityProxy_B,C,D.

When I look at the JSON returned to the client I can even find data which is stored as attribute of entProxC, so I assume the object graph is built correctly and sent to the client.

BUT what happens now in my OnSuccess of the "save" call is like follows

```
 public void onSuccess(EntityProxy_A response) {
   MyRequest request = myRequestFactory.getMyRequest();
   EntityProxy_A editableA = request.edit(response);
   ...
```

On calling "edit" I get an error
" ... error Unfrozen bean with null RequestContext ..."
which happens because EntityProxy_C and EntityProxy_D (not the EntityProxy_B in the Set!) return as "frozen = false" and of course at that point also there is no request context. When I look into the JSON I see like entProxC: {} (everything empty in there - no payload).

I found exactly that situation documented in [Link](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/source/browse/trunk_2012/DemoGwtEditor/src/com/gonevertical/client/views/peopleedit/editor/EditPersonWorkFlow.java?r=3185), but I can't see a solution there in the code ... just the error mentioned.

Now my question - should I be able to use RequestFactory like that?

**Solution/Question 2 - my solution for now and is it ok to use requestfactory like that:**

I have now request methods like

```
Request<Void> save(EntityProxy_A);  
Request<EntityProxy_A> createNew();
```

Calling createNew() like in the 1st approach. Now I also have a Instance Variable

```
 EntityProxy_A myWorkA;
 ....
 public void onSuccess(EntityProxy_A response) {
   MyRequest request = myRequestFactory.getMyRequest();
   myWorkA = request.edit(response);
   ...
```

then I do editing on my "myWorkA" and finally.

```
request.save(myWorkA)
       .fire(Receiver<Void>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(Void response) {
             .....
          }
```

Here I get no EntityProxy_A back from the server - anyways I thought why transport everything back to the client (except the newly created ID's from the persisted EntityProxy_B,C,D). So as found I now use EntityProxy.stableId() when I need to have a pointer to a specific EntityProxy on the Client side - which perhaps is anyways better.

In OnSuccess I do

```
 public void onSuccess(Void response) {
   MyRequest request = myRequestFactory.getMyRequest();
   myWorkA = request.edit(myWorkA);
   ...
```

I have already my "myWorkA" so why not make it editable within a new RequestContext and continue editing and save and save and save ...

This works perfectly for me ... my question ... is that a good thing to do?

When I re-save my "myWorkA" which of course has still NULL Entity ID's in it, because I never loaded an up-to-date version from the server - I have no problems, the corresponding entites are updated on the server and not created over and over again (as could be guessed because of the NULL ID's).

If someone could please clear up, why Solution 1 doesn't work (or is not expected to work anyways) and if it's ok to work like shown in Solution 2.

My only other approach left then would be to have something like:

```
Request<Void> save(EntityProxy_A);  
Request<EntityProxy_A> load(Long entProxId);  
Request<EntityProxy_A> createNew();
```

But I don't like that ... traffic ...

Anyways for now - if that is correct usage of RequestFactory - by far I would prefer Solution 2.

Looking forward to your answers.

Greetings, Andreas.